# AWS Database Migration Service causing problem - SQL Server as Source

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, aws-dms

I have a problem using the AWS Database Migration Service for implementing a transactional replication from SQL Server as a source database engine, a help is highly appreciated.

The '**safeguardPolicy**' connection attribute defaults to '**RELY_ON_SQL_SERVER_REPLICATION_AGENT**'. The tools will start mimicking a transaction in the database for preventing the log to be reused and to be able to read as much changes from the active log.

But what is the intended behavior of these safeguard transaction? Will those sessions be stopped at some point? What is the mechanism to start / run for some time / stop such a transaction?

The production databases I manage are in Full recovery mode, with Log backups on each half an hour. The log grows to an enormous size due to the inability for a valid truncation procedure to succeed and because of those safeguard transactions initiated by the DMS tool.

The only solution to a full transaction log due to LOG_SCAN caused by such behavior of DMS for now is to stop the DMS tasks and run a manual truncation of the log, to release space not used. But it is not a solution at all if we need to stop the replication each time such a problem occurs, knowing that it will occur often.

Please share some internals about the tool if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I am encountering the same issue and it is not effective to stop and restart the replication task everytime. Have you found any long term and sustainable solution?

Comment: No, no long term solution found. I tried every possible configuration of the tool and concluded that it is not meant for replicating data. The tool did evolve, from a migration service to a synchronization one. But the mechanisms it uses are not acceptable for a production environment serving huge OLT workload. I ended up enabling a native SQL Server replication with a Remote distributor server.

Comment: Old thread but I think this could be a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122978/aws-dms-unable-to-truncate-sql-transaction-log